# Javascript Extract data from array and send to db

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array that grabs table information and I need to send that data to the db. I am not good with js so please bear with me. The array is...

```
document.getElementById('sroute').onclick=( function(){
          var arrayOfInvoices = $('#rtbl tr:not(:eq(0))').map( function(i,el) { return ({ invoice: el.id, stopnum: i+1 }) } ).get();
          alert(JSON.stringify(arrayOfInvoices));

          arrayOfInvoices.forEach(saveStop);

          function saveStop() {
              alert(arrayOfInvoices[0][0]);
              /*$.post("rec_maint.php",{
                maint: 'invoices',
                rec: "stopnum",
                invoice: saveStop[0][0];
                rstop: saveStop[0][1]});*/
          }


       });
```

and the first alert is...

```
[{"invoice":"148546","stopnum":1},{"invoice":"148541","stopnum":2},{"invoice":"148542","stopnum":3},{"invoice":"148543","stopnum":4},{"invoice":"148558","stopnum":5}]
```

The second alert is giving me 'undefined'. Please help.

Comment: `arrayOfInvoices[0].invoice`

Comment: `arrayOfInvoices[0]` is an object, you need to use keys for further data -> `arrayOfInvoices[0]["invoice"]`, etc

Comment: Do you have a back end?

Comment: I got it.  Before the function I added var cnt=0; and increment that within the function.  The alert in the function is now...alert(arrayOfInvoices[cnt]["invoice"] + " " + arrayOfInvoices[cnt]["stopnum"]); and that worked!  I will use those in the jquery to send to the db.  Thank you!!!

Comment: Turns out there is still a problem.  Although the code works when I just send the data to the alert.  The problem is when I try to use "$.post..."  When the page loads the post function throws "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;" error.  Comment out the invoice and it throws it on the stopnum.